# Why Sitecore create virtual users with all extranet roles?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am not sure about `BuildVirtualUser` method behavior in **Sitecore 6.6 update 3**

I have the following code:

```
bool isAuthenticated = true;
string userName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", "extranet", user.Login);
SC.Security.Accounts.User virtualUser = SC.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, isAuthenticated);
```

but after `BuildVirtualUser` method call virtualUser variable contain all extranet roles.
I expect that just my following code should attach role to user.

```
foreach(var role in user.Permissions)
{
    string domainRole = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", "extranet", "USER_EDIT");
    if (SC.Security.Accounts.Role.Exists(domainRole))
    {                          
        virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Add(domainRole);
    }
}
```

Why does it happening? What do I need to do to fix it?

### **Update 1**

I have discovered that first time  BuildVirtualUser creates user with 0 roles,
roles can be succesfully added, but after logout and login procedure with the same user name, roles that were added during first time automaticaly attaching to new user. In my opinion this bahavior is not good, in case someone can edit user roles in external system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SC.Security.Accounts.User virtualUser = SC.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, true);
            virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
            virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();
```

this code is help to update user roles dynamicly. 
But I still not undetstend why sitecore cache roles for virtual users.

Comment: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=42524 this might help, understanding why sitecore is caching the sitecore guy says it's for supporting performance :/.

Comment: Hey there. I created a virtual user from an already existing Sitecore user (using same credentials), and my problem is that even if I log out this virtual user and log in again, it is still recognized as a virtual one. If I clear all the cookies from my browser manually it's not anymore, but from code it doesn't work. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
user.Roles.Add(Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(domainRole));
```

from:

```
http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf
```

I am not sure what your for each loop is, but it's kind of redundant your not doing anything with each 'role'.

Comment: sitecore recomend to use RuntimeSettings for virtual users